# how to call getWriteableDatabase from within a different class?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

i want to call getWriteableDatabase from within my Activity class

i know that you can use this.getWriteableDatabase from within the SQLiteOpenHelper

but how do i do it from my Activity? lets say my SQLite helper is named "DatabaseHandler"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare an instance and then you can.use the associated.methods.

```
myDbHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
db= myDbHandler.getWritableDatabase
```